# Google People Api: Country not returned in Adresses field

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-signin, google-authentication, google-people-api

I am trying to get the authenticated user's **country** by specifying "addresses" field in the People Api request as specified [here](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get).
This is the code:

```
router.post("/test_scope", (req, res) => {
  const { idToken, accessToken } = req.body;
  authenticationServices
    .validateGoogleAccessToken(idToken, accessToken)
    .then((response) => {
      res.json(response);
    });
});


const validateGoogleAccessToken = async (idToken, accessToken) => {
  try {
    const CLIENT_ID =
      "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);

    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken,
      audience: CLIENT_ID,
    });

    const payload = ticket.getPayload();

    const { OAuth2 } = google.auth;
    const oauth2Client = new OAuth2();
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({ access_token: accessToken });

    const peopleAPI = google.people({
      version: "v1",
      auth: oauth2Client,
    });

    const { data } = await peopleAPI.people.get({
      resourceName: "people/me",
      personFields: "birthdays,genders,addresses",
    });

    const { birthdays, genders, addresses, ageRanges } = data;
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error);
    throw new Error("Google token validation failed");
  }
};
```

I have set up the [addresses information](https://pay.google.com/gp/w/u/0/home/addressbook) in the account I am using to sign-in like this:

[image]

The is the whole response I get after sending the request:

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
  "etag": "%XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "genders": [
      {
          "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                  "type": "PROFILE",
                  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
              }
          },
          "value": "female",
          "formattedValue": "Female"
      }
  ],
  "birthdays": [
      {
          "metadata": {
              "primary": true,
              "source": {
                  "type": "PROFILE",
                  "id": "1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
              }
          },
          "date": {
              "month": 8,
              "day": 9
          }
      },
      {
          "metadata": {
              "source": {
                  "type": "ACCOUNT",
                  "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx"
              }
          },
          "date": {
              "year": 1996,
              "month": 8,
              "day": 9
          }
      }
  ],
  "addresses": [
    {
        "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
                "type": "PROFILE",
                "id": "111110367350060808978"
            }
        },
        "formattedValue": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX, XXXXX, XXXXX",
        "type": "home",
        "formattedType": "Home"
    }
],
}
```

As you see the country field is missing in "addresses.

---

**NOTE:** I am retrieving the `idToken` and the `accessToken` from the FrontEnd, after  the user clicks on the SignIn button:

```
import GoogleLogin from "react-google-login";

export class LoginPage extends Component {
  onGoogleSignInSucceeded(response) {
    const { accessToken, tokenId } = response;
  }
  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <GoogleLogin
          clientId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"
          scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read"
          // IMPORTANT
          // https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get#authorization-scopes
          buttonText="Sign-in with your Google account"
          onSuccess={this.onGoogleSignInSucceeded}
          onFailure={this.onGoogleSignInFailed}
          cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell us more about why would you need to validate a user's country?

Comment: @Martí I need that info to save it in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All fields on the address field are optional ([see docs](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#address)). This also includes the country. There is also no guarantee that the data is actually correct (the user can add invalid data to their google profile), so be careful about that and check for the `verified` metadata ([see docs](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.FieldMetadata)).

That being said you could try using a geocoding API to get the country from the formatted address. This could be made by using a reverse geocoding query ([Google Geocoding API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#ReverseGeocoding)).

Also notice that there are other fields that may contain an address. For example `locations` ([see docs](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person.Location)) can contain information about where they live.